# The referenced component for anyCPU platform could not be found

Tags: .net, nuget, uwp, platform, nuget-package-restore

My NuGet package contains .dll files that are build for specific platforms (arm, x86 and x64). It was created by the guide http://dontcodetired.com/blog/post/Creating-a-Windows-Store-App-NuGet-Package-for-ARM-x86-and-x64.aspx. Packages works fine, except one fact, I receiving warning from code analize with a following content: The referenced component 'C:...\1.0.0.8\build\uap10.0'
[image]
the same in solution
[image: the same in solution]

My nuget.targets file:
[image]

Comment: Just don't use the AnyCPU solution platform when your component clearly has a strong dependency on the cpu type.  Pretty unclear how this happened, a project that targets UWP never includes AnyCPU.  Just remove it.

Comment: Yea, i can just delete the reference from project, but warning comes again when i reopen project. Nuget.targets file, don't know why, trying to download assembly for AnyCPU. Could it be possible because of one of the assemblies in package targets AnyCPU platform?

Comment: Do you have a Analyzer that is giving the warning or is this an MSBuild warning?